# Parametrisation of curves in 3D and using properties of $\mathbf{r}(t)$ to show that the curve is on the surface of a sphere.

Tags: geometry

A curve $C$ in $\mathbb R^3$ has a parametrisation $\mathbf r(t)$. Suppose $\mathbf r(t)\neq 0 \,\forall t\in \mathbb R$ and $\mathbf r(t)\cdot\mathbf r'(t)=0$ for all points of $C$. Show that $C$ must lie on the surface of a sphere centred at the origin.

I can see why the dot product is $0$ if you have a sphere centred at the origin
($\cos x \sin x - \cos x \sin x + 0 = 0$) but I cannot prove this the other way round. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\frac{d}{dt}\|r(t)\|_2^2 = 2\, r(t)\cdot r'(t) = 0$, the Euclidean norm of $r(t)$ is constant.